# Listening files from FTP server in android

Tags: android, ftp, ftp-client

I want to get Name of all the files from FTP directory and display in List view.
I know how to download/upload file but i don't know how to get name of all the files from FTP Server and display in ListView

My directory at FTP Server is

```
                    /books/mathematics
```

Now i want to fetch all files from  **mathematics** and display in Listview

Comment: Use the list command.

Comment: @greenapps bro, can you please give me some code? i really don't know how to get name of all the files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the apache FTP library from http://www.docjar.com/jar_detail/commons-net-ftp-2.0.jar.html and add it to your libs. Now check the below code.

```
ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
FTPClient ftpclient = new FTPClient();
ftpclient.connect(server, portnumber);
ftpclient.login(username, password);
ftpclient.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
FTPFile[] ftpFiles = ftpclient.listFiles(dir_path);
   for (FTPFile file : ftpFiles) {
       Log.i("TAG", file.getName());
       listItems.add(file.getName());
   }
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
setListAdapter(adapter);
ftpClient.logout();
ftpClient.disconnect();
```

Comment: Thank you providing the useful code,its working 100%